# Trying to import a project from a windows computer to a mac

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to import a project from a windows computer to a mac using the eclipse ide
This is what I did
On the windows computer
1. ledt clicked on project name and selected export.
2. Choose general and archive file
3. clicked next and finish

oN the apple
1. On file menu choose import
2. On general choose Existing project into workspace
3. clicked fiish.

The project appeared in my workspace but had a bunch of errors.  It had a error for all the imports saying"import java.net cannot be resolved" seems like it cannot find any of the libraries

code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; -ERROR SAYING IMPORT CANNOT BE RESOLVED
import java.io.InputStream; -ERROR SAYING IMPORT CANNOT BE RESOLVED
import java.io.InputStreamReader; -ERROR SAYING IMPORT CANNOT BE RESOLVED
import java.net.URL; -ERROR SAYING IMPORT CANNOT BE RESOLVED


import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection; -ERROR IMPLCET SUPER CONSTRUCTER NEEDED


public class cStart {  -ERROR IMPLCET SUPER CONSTRUCTER NEEDED


    public static void main (String[] args) {  -ERROR STRING CANNOT BERESOLVED TO A TYPE


        cTestServer Start1=new cTestServer(0);
        cTestServer Start2=new cTestServer(1);
        cTestServer Start3=new cTestServer(2);
        cTestServer Start4=new cTestServer(3);
        cTestServer Start5=new cTestServer(4);
        cTestServer Start6=new cTestServer(5);
        cTestServer Start7=new cTestServer(6);
        cTestServer Start8=new cTestServer(7);
        cTestServer Start9=new cTestServer(8);
        cTestServer Start10=new cTestServer(9);
        cTestServer Start11=new cTestServer(10);






        Start1.start();
        Start2.start();
        Start3.start();
        Start4.start();
        Start5.start();
        Start6.start();
        Start7.start();
        Start8.start();
        Start9.start();
        Start10.start();
        Start11.start();

        do
        {

        Start1.run(); 
        Start2.run(); 
        Start3.run();       
        Start4.run();       
        Start5.run(); 
        Start6.run();       
        Start7.run();       
        Start8.run();       
        Start9.run(); 
        Start10.run();      
        Start11.run();      



         try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } while(true);
}


}
```

Comment: Okay, dude you've been here a little while now. Can you fix the formatting on this please?

Comment: Do you have installed and configured JDK? In your case it's pure Java classes are not visable by Mac IDE. Check your project configuration if Java JDK/JRE is pressend in libraries.

Comment: What happens when you just create new project and add your one code file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fix the `JRE System Library Dependency` in you Build Path.

Project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Library (Tab).

Remove the (may) existing `JRE System Library`

Use the `Add Library` button to add a Library. In the Dialog choose `JRE System Library` -> Next. On the next page you can either choose one or if you click on `Installed JREs...` you are able to define a new JRE which you can use afterwards.